# Project file can't be build error you don't have permission to view it

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

Hello may be this is silly question and may be asked before it but i am not getting proper solution for this. I have downloaded one project from the internet and when i am trying to run it/build it the xcode says :

The file “PROJECT NAME” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it..

Can anybody have idea why this is happen ? Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Did you check the permissions on the project files and folders in Finder?

Comment: No i didn't check the permission.... Do i have to check xcodeproj file permission?
It is read and write ? What it should be?

Comment: All files (and folders) of the project should have read/write.

Comment: I have resolve the issue by following way.
The project i have download from the internet don't have the executable file in info.plist which should be there and its value should be this ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}. Instead of this value it consist some different value. So i have changed it ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} this value then clean->build->run successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolve the issue by following way. The project i have download from the internet don't have the executable file in info.plist which should be there and its value should be this ${EXECUTABLE_NAME}. Instead of this value it consist some different value. So i have changed it ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} this value then clean->build->run successfully.

See the below link also

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355361/error-while-build-project-xcode-says-you-dont-have-permission#

Answer (score 0):

That's because you may using the repository cloned from the git or svn. Try to clone another new version and run it.

Comment: This obviously is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just had same error, I had number 2015 in executable name. When I removed it, build start working. I tried to add some digit to any part of executable name but this stops build from working. Very odd really.

EDIT:

EXECUTABLE_NAME is generated from [PRODUCT_NAME][EXECUTABLE_PREFIX][EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX]. Details [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html)

Comment: Have you see the answer on the stack i have post above it will help you if you do have anyother error in the project as it consist more answer and more precise.

Comment: Check my EDIT to understand it further.